# [Javascript]Passing local vars as parameters to EnventListener Click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to pass a local variable value to a function.
My code can only alert the local var when it's not used as a parameter to another function.
When I try to pass the value.
Here's my code, it's from the file 'test.js':

```
function test() 
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].id != null) {
            var element = document.createElement("div");
            var currentId = divs[i].id;

            element.className = 'myclass';

           //alert(currentId); <-- Correct value

            element.addEventListener("click", function(){
                alert(currentId);// <-- Value == null ?!
            }, false);

            divs[i].appendChild(element);
        }
    }
}
```

---

This code is from manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
          ...
          "js": ["test.js"]
        }
```

If I use divs[i].id directly, instead of currentId var, Chrome console reports:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
(anonymous function)

Comment: This is the "closure in a loop" problem. On time of execution of the click handler, the loop in which the handler has been created has already ended, therefore the value of "currentId" is that of the last loop cycle (obviously it is "null" there) and NOT the value of the time of creation of the event handler. Solutions: 1. inner closure, 2. function factory ... both will close the CURRENT value of currentId at time of binding of the event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Closure inside a loop" problem (see my comment on your original post)

Try this

```
function test() 
{
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        if (divs[i].id != null) {
            var element = document.createElement("div");
            var currentId = divs[i].id;

            element.className = 'myclass';

            //alert(currentId); <-- Correct value

            element.addEventListener("click", functionFactory(currentId), false);

            divs[i].appendChild(element);
        }
    }
}

function functionFactory(_localId) {
   return function(){
      alert(_localId);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the id dynamically in the event listener.

```
element.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    alert(e.target.parentNode.id);
}, false);
```

Comment: I think the code of OP shows that the clicked `element` doesn't have the id of the original `div` with class `post`